# Syntax Error during Plumi/Plone buildout

Tags: python, linux, plone, buildout

I'm trying to install Plumi 4.5.1 which is based on Plone.

Target system is a:

3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1 (2015-05-24) x86_64

(Debian GNU/Linux 8)

I'm following this guide

https://mgogoulos.trinket.io/plumi-4-5#/installation/installation

and after doing all prior steps successfully, when i try to run the buildout in Step 4 as following:

./bin/python  bootstrap.py && ./bin/buildout -v

I get this error:

```
root@suhail:/home/plumi/PLUMI/plumi.app# ./bin/python  bootstrap.py && ./bin/buildout -v
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bootstrap.py", line 61, in <module>
    ).read() in ez
  File "<string>", line 1
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there anybody which can give me a hint ?

Looks like the bootstrap.py is read as an HTML file (!?).

I already tried deleting and re-cloning the repository.

Comment: `bootstrap.py` tries to load a Python script and execute it, but that loading fails as HTML is returned instead. Perhaps the Plumi bootstrap script is outdated and points to an URL that no longer works.

Comment: hi Marijn thanks for replying! I see this in the bootstrap.py except ImportError:
    ez = {}
    exec urllib2.urlopen('http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py'
                         ).read() in ez
    ez['use_setuptools'](to_dir=tmpeggs, download_delay=0, no_fake=True)  It's the only URL i can find inside the bootstrap.py and its not valid i tried browsing it and a HTML page is displayed.. Maybe this is the problem ? I'am looking for another version of that file which is not broken now.

Comment: The URL on line 61 in ```bootstrap.py``` redirects to a HTML page, instead of  the ```distribute_setup.py``` file. You can try replacing the URL with [this one](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/oodt/tools/oodtsite.publisher/trunk/distribute_setup.py).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Plumi bootstrap script tries to install `setuptools` from an outdated URL:

```
exec urllib2.urlopen('http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py'
                     ).read() in ez
```

The domain name `python-distribute.org` now redirects to a link farm.

The Plumi project should fix their bootstrap script ASAP, but you can fix this locally by replacing the URL with `https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/f657df1f1ed46596d236376649c99a470662b4ba/distribute_setup.py` as a temporary workaround. This is the URL that the [official buildout 1.x `bootstrap.py` now uses](http://downloads.buildout.org/1/bootstrap.py).

The domain name is gone because the `distribute` is long dead; it was a fork of `setuptools` that merged back into the main project.

Comment: Hi Martijn, Thanks for checking into this and explaining me how the bootstrap script is used. I will write on the Plumi Mailing List and ask to fix this ASAP. As for now i tried using the link provided by puzzlepalace and it worked (https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/oodt/tools/oodtsite.publisher/trunk/distribute_setup.py), the buildout finally got executed !

Comment: I am now stuck for on some python package build problem i think, but i will open another Question for this :-(

Comment: The URL puzzleplace provided is an older revision of what I provided (version 0.6.14 vs 0.6.49 of distribute); the link I provided is the official repository of `setuptools` where `distribute` merged into.

Comment: OK ! Replaced link with https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/f657df1f1ed46596d236376649c99a470662b4ba/distribute_setup.py and retried buildout. The build can start succesfully also using this link :-)

Comment: And now you get the 'newer' `distutils` version with more fixes as a bonus. :-) Glad to have been of help!